# MVC 3 Page navigation security rules

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 application which follows PRG pattern, I am looking for a best way to define navigation rules to my application. For example I have application with pages A, B, C and D. Lets say A is a logon page. After user logon successfully, user will be redirected to page B. Now I do not want let the user to type url of page C in the address bar and get access to page C (Page C should be accessible only after POST ing page B or from Page D back button)  I have to setup similar rules for all other pages as well (lets say when user is in page D, should not allow them to get into Page B)

currently I have one option where I can check the @Request.UrlRefferer property to get the source of the every request and decide which page to redirect to. I am not sure this is a best solution.

Appreciate your feedbacks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up doing this task as below:

1. On successful completion of every page, save the page Name in database
2. When user request for a new page, simply check the page they have completed last from database and decide what to do.

I chooses this approach simply because it will definitely **help during Problem Solving/Troubleshooting once application is in Production**, which is huge for me.

Thanks everyone for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Do not base your security on this. Use the [Authorize] attribute to define security. The UrlReferrer can easily be forged as well.

Why are you trying to limit this? If you have a business reason the user most go through a particular flow, then consider either a cookie, session, or database entry to note their current 'completion' status - IE some somewhat persistent method to determine this. You could also form a token based on say - a session id - that gets passed into each page. If the token exists and matches the user's current session , then load the page for them. Of course this could be forged if the user understands this - but if you are simply trying to ensure the proper flow then this is a way as well. The user would not get a link with the current session id in it until they hit the prior step.

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes, I am trying to do this to ensure proper flow. I like the idea of storing the completion status in session and set the rules based on that. however as you mentioned both UrlRerrer and seesion id can be forged, wondering is there any best way to do this?

Comment: If you aren't worried about 'manual fiddling' then either method would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a particular page to be accessible via the URL, one option available is to make sure there's no way to access the page via a URL. To access the page, make a POST action that will return a view rather than a redirect. This would mean the view your POST action returns will be shown on a page with the URL of the previous page. For exameple:

Page A URL is `/login` and after logging in, the user is redirected to Page B. The URL is now `/home`. Page B sends a POST request and the contents of the page becomes Page C but the URL still remains as `/home`. The only way to view the contents of Page C would be to visit Page B and send a POST request.

This breaks the PRG pattern but that's one option.

There is one more alternative, store the current permissions of the user indicating which page they're allowed to enter and check if the user is authorized to view a page before executing the action. You could place the code in an `ActionAttribute` which you can apply to your action methods or entire controllers. If you'd like a more detailed explanation of this technique, leave me a comment and I'll write up another answer describing this technique in more detail.

---

Here's a quick proof-of-concept of the technique described above:

```
public class PermissionsNeeded : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string expectedPermission;

    public PermissionsNeeded(string permission)
    {
        expectedPermission = permission;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var currentPermissions = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentPermissions"] as IEnumerable<string> ?? new List<string>();

        // If user does NOT have permission to access the action method
        if(!currentPermissions.Contains(expectedPermission)
        {
            throw new HttpException(403, "User is not authorized to view this page");
        }
    }
}

class YourController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PageB()
    {
        var currentPermissions = Session["CurrentPermissions"] ?? new List<string>();
        currentPermissions.Add("PostedFromPageB");
        Session["CurrentPermissions"] = currentPermissions;

        return RedirectToAction("PageC");
    }

    [PermissionsNeeded("PostedFromPageB")
    public ActionResult PageC()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Currently, the custom attribute will only accept one permission at a time which is a simply limitation to rectify. You'd be responsible for removing the permissions stored in the Session when you feel the user shouldn't have certain permissions anymore. I threw an HttpException that return a 403 status code (unauthorized access) but if you'd instead like to return an ActionResult such as a `RedirectToRoute` or a `View`, you could set a value to the `filterContext.Result` property.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not like to break PRG pattern. can you explain your other option?

Comment: @matmat: added a proof-of-concept for the alternate method I described earlier. Will probably need some changes to make it fit your needs exactly. If you need any clarifications about it, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response, even though your approach is one option, I decided to go with database as it helps during troubleshooting purposes. please refer my answer below.